Azure CLI update metric alert with custom properties for Threshold Update
I am trying to update the threshold value from 0 to 10 for Failed SQL Connection for Metric Alerts.
I am running below CLI command but its failing. Please help:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  name: FixAlertSQLFailedConnections
  displayName: Fix Azure Alert Issue for SQL Failed Connection
  inputs:
  azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
  scriptType: "bash"
  scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
  inlineScript: |
  az monitor metrics alert update --resource-group myresourcegrougname --name "Failed SQL Connections" --add-condition "Threshold > 10"

Threshold value must change from 0 to 10 for this Alert Name
Error:
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" C:\Data\Agent\_work\_temp\azureclitaskscript1728481202675.sh
line 1:10 extraneous input '>' expecting {'.', '/', '-', '_', '\', ':', '%', ',', '|', '(', ')', NUMBER, QUOTE, WHITESPACE, WORD}
line 1:14 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting OPERATOR
ERROR: usage error: --condition {avg,min,max,total,count} [NAMESPACE.]METRIC
                         [{=,!=,>,>=,<,<=} THRESHOLD]
                         [{<,>,><} dynamic SENSITIVITY VIOLATION of EVALUATION [since DATETIME]]
                         [where DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...]
                         [and   DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...] ...]]
                         [with skipmetricvalidation]


Can you check the --add-condition parameter properly as error throws there. @Kishlay Anand

According to az monitor metrics alert update,

--add-condition --add-conditions Usage: --add-condition {avg,min,max,total,count} [NAMESPACE.]METRIC [{=,!=,>,>=,<,<=} THRESHOLD] [{<,>,><} dynamic SENSITIVITY VIOLATIONS of EVALUATIONS [since DATETIME]] [where DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...] [and DIMENSION {includes,excludes} VALUE [or VALUE ...] ...]]

If Threshold is your custom metric, the correct syntax should be --add-condition "count Threshold > 10".
If the Threshold mentioned by you is the one shown below, you can update it using az monitor metrics alert update --resource-group {rgName} --name {alertName} --set criteria.allOf.[0].threshold=10.

Result:

